# Keras intermediate layer output to calculate the loss

Tags: model, keras, theano, layer, loss

I am using Keras with theano, to train an autoencoder model.
I want to use an intermediate layer representation of the model to do some specific calculation in the loss function (a custom loss function to the same model).

How could I do this?

I can output the intermediate layer from the model. But then it will be trained using 2 outputs instead one. I want to train the model only using the final output.

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to modify the loss so that it depends on some internal state of the network as well as the output?

Comment: exactly..I want to define the loss function using the internal feature representation of an intermediate layer + output..for this I need to access the output of the intermediate layer as one of the output of the model. But normal way like `classifier = Model(input=input, output=[intermediate, final]` will train the network for both outputs, which I don't need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.

```
model1 = Model(input=x, output=y1)
model2 = Model(input=x, output=[y2,y3])

model1.compile((optimizer='sgd', loss=cutom_loss_function)
model2.compile((optimizer='sgd', loss=cutom_loss_function)

model2.fit(data, [targets2, targets3], , nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

However, I want my `cutom_loss_function` to access the output of `model1`, (`y1`) to calculate the loss. But when I use `model1.output[0]` inside `cutom_loss_function()` it gives the below error.

```
ValueError: GpuElemwise. Input dimension mis-match. Input 1 (indices start at 0) has shape[2] == 48, but the output's size on that axis is 2304.
Apply node that caused the error: GpuElemwise{Composite{sqr((i0 - scalar_sigmoid((i1 + i2))))}}[(0, 1)](GpuDimShuffle{x,0,1,2}.0, GpuCorrMM{half, (1, 1)}.0, GpuReshape{4}.0)
Toposort index: 341
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, False, False, False)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D), CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, True, True, True))]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 1, 2304, 2), (1, 1, 48, 48), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(0, 0, 1, 2304), (0, 0, 48, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', CudaNdarray([[[[ 0.]]]])]
Outputs clients: [[GpuReshape{2}(GpuElemwise{Composite{sqr((i0 - 
scalar_sigmoid((i1 + i2))))}}[(0, 1)].0, MakeVector{dtype='int64'}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```